# getting the first table of a odt document

Tags: java, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer, odt

In my Java application I have to read in data from an .odt document.
Can somebody tell me how to get a reference to the first table in such a document?
I wanted to use the Apache odf toolkit, but there I only found a method to get the table by name:

```
 TextDocument doc = TextDocument.loadDocument("/Users/me/Desktop/someFile.odt");
 Table t = doc.getTableByName("0");
```

My document contains one large table I need to parse, but I don't know its name..
Is there a way to find it out?
Or an other way to get the table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `doc.getTableList()` to get a list of all the tables in the document.